# CQ/AEM Dispatcher does not flush Binaries

Tags: aem, dispatcher

Our application imports binaries (mostly PDF) from a legacy system and stores them on a page together with some metadata.

If there was a change the page automatically gets activated. We see the replication events in the replication log and also on the dispatcher an invalidate event is logged. But there is no eviction entry and this the old binary is still cached.

We also have HTML pages next to these container pages for the binaries and they work as expected. Here the two log entries for the successful html and the unsuccessful PDF:

### OK:

```
[Thu Jul 03 09:26:33 2014] [D] [27635(24)] Found farm website for localhost:81 
[Thu Jul 03 09:26:33 2014] [D] [27635(24)] checking [/dispatcher/invalidate.cache] 
[Thu Jul 03 09:26:33 2014] [I] [27635(24)] Activation detected: action=Activate [/content/offering/s2p/en/offerings/documents/Swiss_Mandate_Line/Review/test] 
[Thu Jul 03 09:26:33 2014] [I] [27635(24)] Touched /app/C2Z/dyn/c2zcqdis/docroot/.stat 
[Thu Jul 03 09:26:33 2014] [I] [27635(24)] Evicted /app/C2Z/dyn/c2zcqdis/docroot/content/offering/s2p/en/offerings/documents/Swiss_Mandate_Line/Review/test.html 
[Thu Jul 03 09:26:33 2014] [D] [27635(24)] response.status = 200 
[Thu Jul 03 09:26:33 2014] [D] [27635(24)] response.headers[Server] = "Communique/2.6.3 (build 5221)" 
[Thu Jul 03 09:26:33 2014] [D] [27635(24)] response.headers[Content-Type] = "text/html" 
[Thu Jul 03 09:26:33 2014] [D] [27635(24)] cache flushed 
[Thu Jul 03 09:26:33 2014] [I] [27635(24)] "GET /dispatcher/invalidate.cache" 200 13 2ms
```

### Not OK

```
[Thu Jul 03 09:30:45 2014] [D] [27635(24)] Found farm website for localhost:81 
[Thu Jul 03 09:30:45 2014] [D] [27635(24)] checking [/dispatcher/invalidate.cache] 
[Thu Jul 03 09:30:45 2014] [I] [27635(24)] Activation detected: action=Activate [/content/offering/s2p/en/offerings/documents/Swiss_Mandate_Line/Review/as2p_vvm_ch_gl_fix_chf__pdf] 
[Thu Jul 03 09:30:45 2014] [I] [27635(24)] Touched /app/C2Z/dyn/c2zcqdis/docroot/.stat 
[Thu Jul 03 09:30:45 2014] [D] [27635(24)] response.status = 200 
[Thu Jul 03 09:30:45 2014] [D] [27635(24)] response.headers[Server] = "Communique/2.6.3 (build 5221)" 
[Thu Jul 03 09:30:45 2014] [D] [27635(24)] response.headers[Content-Type] = "text/html" 
[Thu Jul 03 09:30:45 2014] [D] [27635(24)] cache flushed 
[Thu Jul 03 09:30:45 2014] [I] [27635(24)] "GET /dispatcher/invalidate.cache" 200 13 1ms
```

The PDF in this case is stored in a node called 'download' directly below the jcr:content node. It's html container is never called directly and this is not available on the dispatcher. So a user directly requests the file:
`/content/offering/s2p/en/offerings/documents/Swiss_Mandate_Line/Review/as2p_vvm_ch_gl_fix_chf__pdf/jcr%3acontent/download/file.res/as2p_vvm_ch_gl_fix_chf_.pdf`

In the dispatcher.any we flush all html pages on activation, but not for the binaries. For testing, we added an **allow *.pdf** but this didn't help anyway.

```
/invalidate
{
/0000
  {
  /glob "*"
  /type "deny"
  }
/0001
  {
  /glob "*.html"
  /type "allow"
  }
}
```

In my opinion, the invalidate call should just delete the whole folder:
`/content/offering/s2p/en/offerings/documents/Swiss_Mandate_Line/Review/as2p_vvm_ch_gl_fix_chf__pdf`

Any ideas why our binaries do not get flushed?

UPDATE: In another post the `statfileslevel` property in the dispatcher.any is mentioned. In our environment this is commented out. Could it be that this could be the problem. Sadly I don't fully understand how this is supposed to work. Is the level meant from the wwwroot or from the page that is activated?

Comment: Thanks for the formatting Dave, didn't see that you can format logs like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your problem with dispatcher flushing is that the path the file is being served from is using `jcr%3acontent` when it should use `_jcr_content`.

Dispatcher flushing deletes the folder `_jcr_content` under the path that is being flushed.  It does not delete `jcr%3acontent` (urldecoded as `jcr:content`).  So you should instead serve the pdf using this URL:
`/content/offering/s2p/en/offerings/documents/Swiss_Mandate_Line/Review/as2p_vvm_ch_gl_fix_chf__pdf/_jcr_content/download/file.res/as2p_vvm_ch_gl_fix_chf_.pdf`

This would then cache the pdf file under:
`{CACHEROOT}/content/offering/s2p/en/offerings/documents/Swiss_Mandate_Line/Review/as2p_vvm_ch_gl_fix_chf__pdf/_jcr_content/download/file.res/as2p_vvm_ch_gl_fix_chf_.pdf`

Then when this path is flushed it will delete the subdirectory `_jcr_content` under the path of the flush
`/content/offering/s2p/en/offerings/documents/Swiss_Mandate_Line/Review/as2p_vvm_ch_gl_fix_chf__pdf`

To go into more detail, when you issue a flush request for path above then the following files and directories are deleted:

- `/content/offering/s2p/en/offerings/documents/Swiss_Mandate_Line/Review/as2p_vvm_ch_gl_fix_chf__pdf.*` where * is a wildcard
- `/content/offering/s2p/en/offerings/documents/Swiss_Mandate_Line/Review/as2p_vvm_ch_gl_fix_chf__pdf/_jcr_content`

See slide 23 in this presentation for details on how flushing works:
http://www.slideshare.net/andrewmkhoury/aem-cq-dispatcher-caching-webinar-2013

Comment: Thanks for this input, I'll try that next week and let you know if it worked.

Comment: Successfully tested it. Thanks again for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the root cause, but what I suspect you probably need to do, is to go to localhost:4503/etc/replication/agents.publish.html (note, this is a publish instance, you can do it on the author and replicate the replication agents et al, but for the purposes of the POC, just do it directly on the publisher.)

Then go to your dispatcher flush agent, and click on edit settings.

Go to the triggers panel.

Make sure that the "On Receive" trigger is checked. What this does is enable chain replication, meaning that when a direct asset is published, it is directly deleted from the dispatcher, causing a miss on the next request, and thus pulling a fresh copy from the dispatcher.

Note that this kind of flushing is distinct from the stats file level flushing, which only flushes a directory, rather than a fully qualified path to the asset.

---

By the way, it's not stats file level. The stats file level by default is 0 if it is commented out, which invalidates anything below. What you seem to be looking for is an active delete of the cache. This is possible, as Dave just outlined to me for an unrelated problem in this post:
[Is it possible to recursively flush directories in the CQ5/AEM apache dispatcher?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24946526/is-it-possible-to-recursively-flush-directories-in-the-cq5-aem-apache-dispatcher/24955006#24955006)

An approach would be to create a flush interceptor. Essentially a custom servlet on the publisher. What you would then do, is to configure the normal flush replicator to make a call to the local servlet on the publisher.

The servlet then detects whether it would need to delete the directory, or any particular files within. It can transform the flush path to the required path, and instead of a FLUSH  action, use a DELETE action.

It would still be very important to send the flush to the normal dispatcher location.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the "On Receive" is checked and as I mentioned we don't have DAM Assets here, but binaries directly attached to a page. And with that of course only the page gets activated, expecting that the whole folder structure generated on the dispatcher gets evicted as well, which sadly isn't the case.

Comment: Added another approach and explained the stats file level.